# Criação de csv vazio

Tags: python, csv

olá

sobre o código de python abaixo, quero criar um csv com o somatório de habitantes em cada estado

mas ele cria um arquivo csv vazio

por favor, alguém tem ideia do problema?

o arquivo csv original em que busquei os dados é este: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B72DpG1W01nneHU5UXh0TzdSSVU

código:

```
import csv

brasil = csv.DictReader(open('municipios-brasil.csv', encoding='utf-8'))

total = {}

for municipio in brasil:
    estado = municipio['estado']
    habitantes = int(municipio['habitantes'])

    if estado not in total:
        total[estado] = 0

    total[estado] = total[estado] + habitantes

arquivo = open('habitantes.csv', mode = 'w', encoding = 'utf-8')

resultado = csv.DictWriter(arquivo, fieldnames = ['estado', 'habitantes'])

resultado.writeheader()

for estado, habitantes in total.items():
    resultado.writerow({'estado': estado, 'habitantes':habitantes})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se executar o seu código de no REPL (IDLE, ipython, ou o próprio python) o arquivo não ira fechar e as mudanças não serão 'flushed' (escritas) ao arquivo.

Assim apenas adicione a linha `arquivo.close()` no fim do seu script e as mudanças serão escritas ao seu arquivo.

Um jeito de evitar que isso aconteça é usar os gerenciadores de contexto, vulgo a palavra `with` em python. O que essa sintaxe faz, no caso de arquivos é executar o método `close()` no objeto assim que o código sai da identação. No seu caso, seria algo assim:

```
import csv

brasil = csv.DictReader(open('municipios-brasil.csv', encoding='utf-8'))

total = {}

for municipio in brasil:
    estado = municipio['estado']
    habitantes = int(municipio['habitantes'])

    if estado not in total:
        total[estado] = 0

    total[estado] = total[estado] + habitantes

with open('habitantes.csv', mode = 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as arquivo:

    resultado = csv.DictWriter(arquivo, fieldnames = ['estado', 'habitantes'])

    resultado.writeheader()

    for estado, habitantes in total.items():
        resultado.writerow({'estado': estado, 'habitantes':habitantes})'
```

Assim que o interpretador chegar no fim do bloco do `with` ele irá executar o método de saída, que para objetos do tipo `file` (aqueles criados com o `open` por exemplo), como a variável/objeto `arquivo`, é o método `close()`. No caso, ao chegar no fim da indentação do `with` será executado `arquivo.close()` e as alterações que o `resultado` faz são escritas para o disco (i.e. salvas).

Você pode ler sobre a sintaxe do `with` [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with), mas eu acho um pouco críptica a documentação.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves, considere marcar a minha resposta como aceita, assim o pessoal pode achar ela e revisar

Comment: Claro, funcionou sim. Mas não sei onde aceitar as respostas

Comment: É um tick embaixo da caixa de voto ^_^